# How do you say `[` and `[[`?

Tags: r, subset, terminology

`[` and `[[` come up a lot when using R. Suppose that I'm having a conversation about these two functions, what do I actually call these "indexing operators"? I know how to name them as punctuation, but is there anything within R or its documentation that gives them a more specific name? I know that they're subsetting functions that are documented under `?Extract`, but I've never seen anyone call them anything like "extract and double extract".

Comment: In the R Language Definition they are referred to as ["single and double brackets"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-tokens), and in [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) you find several instances of "square bracket" and "double square bracket".

Comment: ...which seems to agree with the general terminology ([wiki brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket), [wiki double brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Double_brackets))

Comment: I've always found "square bracket" to be a little duplicative, personally, since there are "brackets" (which are square), "braces" (which are curly), and "parens". Perhaps I'm just being OCD on terminology ... :-)

Comment: @r2evans Not to mention, the English and the Americans disagree on what's a bracket, brace, and paren.

Comment: I was just typing something to that effect ... *"but it is likely influenced by language, culture, or other issues I'm not exposed to regularly"*. :-)

Comment: @r2evans I don't think the "square" is redundant, given the [slew of brackets out there](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=bracket#characters)...So much for your OCD!

Comment: *Ich spreche kein Unicode* ;-)

Comment: `U+1F923` `U+1F44D` @r2evans

Comment: (I had to look those up, dang it ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the R Language Definition they are referred to as ["single and double brackets"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-tokens):

> Indexing of arrays and vectors is performed using the single and double brackets, `[]` and `[[]]`

In [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) you find several instances of "square bracket" and "double square bracket".

This agrees with the general terminology (see e.g. wikipedia on [square brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Square_brackets) and [double brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Double_brackets), and their [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Unicode)).